# Use the %ld conversion specifier to printf a double type in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Here is part of the source code(example code from the book "C primer plus"):

```
float n1 = 3.0;
double n2 = 3.0;
long n3 = 2000000000;
long n4 = 1234567890;
printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld\n", n1, n2, n3, n4);
```

The expected output is:

```
0 1074266112 0 1074266112
```

The book explicitly explain the reason:

> The mechanics of argument passing depend on the implementation. This
>   is how argument passing works on one system. The function call looks
>   as follows:
>  `printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld\n", n1, n2, n3, n4);` 
> This call
>   tells the computer to hand over the values of the variables n1 , n2 ,
>   n3 , and n4 to the computer. Here’s one common way that’s
>   accomplished. The program places the values in an area of memory
>   called the stack . When the computer puts these values on the stack,
>   it is guided by the types of the variables, not by the conversion
>   specifiers. Consequently, for n1 , it places 8 bytes on the stack (
>   float is converted to double ). Similarly, it places 8 more bytes for
>   n2 , followed by 4 bytes each for n3 and n4 . Then control shifts to
>   the printf() function. This function reads the values off the stack
>   but, when it does so, it reads them according to the conversion
>   specifiers. The %ld specifier indicates that printf() should read 4
>   bytes, so printf() reads the first 4 bytes in the stack as its first
>   value. This is just the first half of n1 , and it is interpreted as a
>   long integer. The next %ld specifier reads 4 more bytes; this is just
>   the second half of n1 and is interpreted as a second long integer (see
>   Figure 4.9 ). Similarly, the third and fourth instances of %ld cause
>   the first and second halves of n2 to be read and to be interpreted as
>   two more long integers, so although we have the correct specifiers for
>   n3 and n4 , printf() is reading the wrong bytes.

I can get what the book says,and the memory my own PC used for each data type is the same as above.
However as I compile and run the code myself,I get the following output:
`2000000000 1234567890 2147483626 0`
My development environment is:*Ubuntu16.04LTS,gcc 5.4.0,C11 standard.*
I don't know what causes the difference between my own output and the expected one.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, plain and simple.

Comment: Probably you're on x64 system where `long` are passed in integer registers and `double` are passed in floating point registers

Comment: It is highly dependent on your specific compiler. You are using a different compiler from the book, so you got a different result.

Comment: It's purely depends on platform, I got 2000000000 1234567890 4195840 140523256637664 [here](http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc)

Comment: People keep saying that this depends on your platform, which is true; yet this is [explicitly undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9): "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." Anything could happen, including differing behaviors on the same platform depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: Your question asks why you are getting the behavior you observe. In case you are also interested in seeing the bits of a double by viewing them through an integer, a proper way to do that is to include `<stdint.h>` and then use `uint64_t y = (union { double d; uint64_t u; }) { x } .u;`. For `float`, change `uint64_t` to `uint32_t` and `double` to `float`. This assumes `float` and `double` are 32 and 64 bits in your implementation.

Comment: Once you have obtained the bits in this way, you can print them by including `<inttypes.h>` and using `printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", y);` for decimal output or `printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", y)` for hexadecimal. That is for `double`. For `float`, change `64` to `32`.

Comment: Tip: to investigate such things, recommend to 1st `printf("%a %a %lX %lX\n", n1,n2,n3,4);`   then follow up and use the investigative `printf("%lx %lx %lx %lx\n", n1, n2, n3, n4);`.  It is much easier to analyze the hexadecimal output than decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here’s one common way that’s accomplished. The program places the values in an area of memory called the stack . When the computer puts these values on the stack, it is guided by the types of the variables, not by the conversion specifiers

This is true on most 32-bits systems, but on 64 bits system, the calling convention is different, and arguments are passed in registers if possible.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) (the System V AMD64 ABI is the one relevant here).

One way to make sure would be to look at the assembly output of your program. Using gcc, you can use `-S` to output assembly instead of a binary.

(Note that I am talking about linux only here. Things may be different depending on your OS, and as this is an undefined behaviour, your compiler or even your compiler version or flags)

Answer (score 3):

From standard §7.21.6.6¶9

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) *If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*

This is the problem in your case. You can read the standard and you will see standard never says that you have to use stack or heap to realize memory access or something similar. To give a reason to the Undefined Behavior - `sizeof (long)` (coming from the `%ld` format specifier) is being read on each of the case and printed. But the amount of memory needed to store a double or some other variable might be different from that. That will print some portion of the original variable in *most cases*. This is undefined behavior and that's the correct way to say it.

Use correct format specifier (`%f` for float and double).